# Run Phonegap applicaton with node-express

Tags: node.js, cordova, rest, express

I wanted to make mobile app from existing  webapp. My webapp is nodejs-exressjs REST API server, with HTML/JS client.
I wanted to leverage API from my REST server, and swap out client with phonegap/cordova based mobile app. 
Till now, the only feasible solution seems to be use CORS, and have phonegap/cordova server and nodejs servers running separately. 
Is there a way I can use same server to deploy both my REST Server, and Phonegap/Cordova Client ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sorry, Cordova apps rely on having the front client in local, and perform calls to server in REST, so your first thought is correct. You can share the REST server for both applications, but the code of the cordova app client is going to be in the devices locally, without need of a server.